# Flutter: How to cancel a task

Tags: flutter

I have a button which when clicked does a calculation, and if the button is pressed again the calculation should stop if it is not finished. How can I cancel the execution of _doCalc here?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  bool _calculating = false;

  void _doCalc() async {
      _setCalculating(true);
      // do some calculation
      ...
      _setCalculating(false);

  }

  void _setCalculating(bool calculating) {
    setState(() {
      _calculating = calculating;

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new RaisedButton(
          child: Text(_calculating ? "Stop" : "Start"),
          onPressed: () {

            if (_calculating) {
              _setCalculating(false);

              // stop execution of _doCalc() ????

            } else {
              _doCalc();
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why don't you disable the button while it's processing?

Comment: What kinda calculation you are doing.. Can you give some example ? Something like stop watch ?

Comment: @diegoveloper That won't work because the calculation has to actually be cancelable.

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian The calculation is just a simple arithmetic equation with parameters from a GET request, and it displays the result (It's for a candidate test for a job). So hitting the button again is supposed to prevent the result from being displayed.

Comment: @tmath Sorry I am not able to understand fully. Are you making network call which you want to stop on button click? If your code is confidential, can you post some similar dummy code?

Comment: normally when you hit a button , you should display a loading dialog or disable the button until the operation finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with some flags,  like this example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _calculating = false;
  bool inProgress = false;

  _doCalc() async {
    // do some calculation
    if (inProgress){
      inProgress = false;
      _setCalculating(false);
      return;
    }
    inProgress = true;
    _setCalculating(true);
    await yourOperation();
    if (inProgress){
      inProgress = false;
      print("DISPLAY YOUR RESULT using setState");
       _setCalculating(false);
      return;
    } else {
        print("don't display because it was cancelled");
       _setCalculating(false);
    }

  }

  Future yourOperation() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
  }

  void _setCalculating(bool calculating) {
    setState(() {
      _calculating = calculating;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new RaisedButton(
            child: Text(_calculating ? "Stop" : "Start"),
            onPressed: () {
              _doCalc();
            },
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, I don't know why I didn't think of this approach.